# Citing two different ways within same document

Tags: citing

I am using the `unsrt` bibliography style which formats references in text as [1]. This is fine most of the time, but occasionally I would like to write it as Reference 1 or [Ref. 1]. Is there a simple way I can do this, such as getting it to drop the square brackets just in the instances where I need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further research it turns out a simple answer is `\citen` from the `cite` package, which returns just the number without any formatting.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\cite{x} \citen{x} [Ref.~\citen{x}] Reference \citen{x}.

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{thebibliography}{bib}
    \bibitem{x} xxxxxx
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This displays as:

[image: citen example]

Answer (score 1):

Below I've defined `\citeA` and `\citeB` which provides the output you need. It sources `\@citeX` which is a partial copy of `\cite` from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co), which checks for undefined references.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Abbreviated grab from LaTeX kernel
\newcommand{\@citeX}[3]{{%
  \@ifundefined{b@#2}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
    \G@refundefinedtrue
    \@latex@warning
      {Citation `#2' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
  {#1\csname b@#2\endcsname#3}}}
\newcommand{\citeA}[1]{\@citeX{[Ref.~}{#1}{]}}
\newcommand{\citeB}[1]{\@citeX{Reference~}{#1}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See~\cite{abc}. See \citeA{abc}. See \citeB{abc}.

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The usage of `\citeX` inside `\citeA` and `\citeB` should be clear enough so you can modify them to suit your needs. `\citeX{<prefix>}{<cite>}{<suffix>}` creates a citation of the form `<prefix><cite><suffix>`.

Answer (score 0):

With `natbib` package you have two optional arguments that allow  include  text before and after the reference number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
Use \citep{IEEEexample:article_typical} 
or \citep[Ref. ][]{IEEEexample:article_typical}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{IEEEexample}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]